# error en listas python

Tags: python, funciones, bucles

de un día para otro cuando tengo una lista con distintos tipos de datos, ejemplo enteros, flotantes, booleanos, no me deja iterar con funciones en la lista, aquí un ejemplo para explicar mejor

```py
lista = [123, 'Hola', 45, 0.2, True]
```

En la lista debo obtener los datos que son numéricos y antes lo hacia con la función `isdigit()` pero ya no me aparece en el editor de texto ninguna función y cuando las uso me dice esto

```py
for i in lista:
    if i.isdigit():
        print(i)
```

**Error**

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isdigit'
```

tengo horas sin saber que pasa

Comment: El problema es que `isdigit` es un método de un string, no de un entero

Comment: entiendo pero estoy iterando la lista, la variable i toma cada valor y deberia evaluarlo, lo que no entiendo es que antes me funcionaba y ahora ni me aparecen

Comment: No, `isdigit()` solo es valido para cadenas, no para otro tipo de dato

Comment: pero si estoy iterando un array, no deberia simplemente evaluar si el i es digito? y si no lo es pues seguir de largo, me da el error y no me aparecen ninguna de las funciones en el vscode

Comment: Si, pero no es la forma, un objeto entero no tiene un método `isdigit()` solo lo tienen los strings  voy a editar mi respuesta añadiendo explicación

Answer (score 2):

El isDigit() solo te arroja True o False, dependiendo si un string tiene  dígitos o no. Es decir, trabaja con strings, no con enteros.

Input : string = '15460'
Output : True

Input : string = '154ayush60'
Output : False

Lo que puedes hacer es usar type para conocer el tipo y usarlo como condicional para imprimirlo:

```
for i in lista:
    if type(i) == int:
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que `isdigit()` es el método de un string, no de un entero.
Vamos a ver que es lo que pasa en tu ciclo `for`.

```py
lista = [123, 'Hola', 45, 0.2, True]

#solo se tomara en cuenta la primera iteracion, esto para hacer breve la explicacion
for i in lista: #i = 123
    if i.isdigit(): #123.isdigit() -> Error
        print(i)
```

Esto produce un error ya que el valor de `i`, en la primera iteración, es `123`, y los números **no tienen** el método `isdigit()` por lo que no pudes hacer `int.isdigit()`. El método `isdigit()` solo sirve para los strings o cadenas, ya que `isdigit()` evalúa si la cadena contenida es un digito. Aqui algo obvio. ¿Para que quieres saber si un entero es un digito, si de por si lo es?, por tal razón no existe lógica alguna para querer evaluar si un objeto de tipo entero (los números), es un digito, ya que de por si ya lo es, lo mismo pasa con los otros tipos de datos.

- ¿para que evaluar si un dato de dato booleano es booleano?
- ¿para que evaluar si un tipo de dato float es float?

Pero con los strings si pasa esto, ya que el string almacena un dato en formato de cadena, un string puede ser `123` o `True`, en este caso desearias evaluar lo que contiene el string, por tal razón los métodos `isdigit()`, `isalpha()`, `isnumeric()`, etc. solo funcionan con los datos de tipo String.

Una solución seria convertir el numero a una cadena utilizando la funcion `str()`, la cual convierte el dato a string o utilizar *f-string*, dado que es un ciclo simple utilizaré una comprensión de lista

```py
lista = [123, 'Hola', 45, 0.2, True]
nums = [i for i in lista if str(i).isdigit()] #utilizamos str()
print(nums)

#su equivalente en ciclo for normal
nums = []
for i in lista:
    f"{i}". isdigit(): #utilizamos f-strings
        nums.append(i)
print(nums)
```

**resultado**

```
[123, 45]
```

Answer (score -1):

Así te puede servir, ya que `isdigit()` es solo para *string* introduces el `i` dentro de un *str*, `str(i)`, si creáramos un lista de solo *string* si podríamos recorrerlo como mencionas, pero ya que se están introduciendo numero debemos transformar cada posición que recorremos a *string* para que pueda hacerse la validación de `isdigit()`.

creamos la lista, recorremos con un `for`, y si `str(i).isdigit()` entrará e imprimirá `i`

```
lista = [123, 'Hola', 45, 0.2, True]
for i in lista:
    if str(i).isdigit():
        print(i)
```

Comment: claro, en breve edito mi respuesta.

Comment: se podría saber por que motivo reviertes la edición?

Comment: Lo siento, fue un error. gracias por la edicion.